# Defining a service across several files in Apache Thrift

Tags: thrift

I'd like to wrap a large C++ library in Apache Thrift.
The interface will probably have tens or hundreds of functions, so it would be messy to put the whole thing in one file.
So, I'd like to spread the service definition across multiple files.
Is there some supported way to do this?

BTW, Thrift's single inheritance is insufficient here.
Multiple inheritance would work, but alas Thrift doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can spread the definitions across multiple files, using `#include`. The Thrift tutorial contains an example for both (a) including one IDL into another and (b) inheriting a service from another.

File shared.thrift:

```
struct SharedStruct {
  1: i32 key
  2: string value
}

service SharedService {
  SharedStruct getStruct(1: i32 key)
}
```

File tutorial.thrift (excerpts only):

```
/**
 * Thrift files can reference other Thrift files to include common struct
 * and service definitions. These are found using the current path, or by
 * searching relative to any paths specified with the -I compiler flag.
 *
 * Included objects are accessed using the name of the .thrift file as a
 * prefix. i.e. shared.SharedObject
 */
include "shared.thrift"

// some more code

exception InvalidOperation {
  1: i32 what,
  2: string why
}

/**
 * Ahh, now onto the cool part, defining a service. Services just need a name
 * and can optionally inherit from another service using the extends keyword.
 */
service Calculator extends shared.SharedService {
   void ping(),
   i32 add(1:i32 num1, 2:i32 num2),
   i32 calculate(1:i32 logid, 2:Work w) throws (1:InvalidOperation ouch),
   oneway void zip()
}
```

### Further recommendations

It could be a good idea to split the huge interface into smaller, thematically grouped, interfaces. Using the [Multiplexer](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1915) introduced with Thrift 0.9.0 it is quite easy, to have multiple services share the same transport. The multiplexer is already supported by a good portion of the total languages supported with Thift today, for details see the linked JIRA ticket.

Comment: Single inheritance won't work for me, as I stated in the original question. Multiplexing gets closer to a solution, though it is not ideal, as it still requires creating a separate client for each service. I might have 20 files / services, so this would be too much for a user.

Comment: You really need all the time all the functions? To me, "*huge interface*" sounds exactly like "*code smell*". Aside from that, sth. around 100 functions plus/minus is not really huge and I dont't think I would loose much sleep over that if this is the way to go. How many different structures etc. will be involved?

Comment: Yes. I'm wrapping OpenCV, a large existing library with a set API.

Comment: Oh, looks like you will have some fun. I think, I'd still try to follow the given API's structure. This way you can re-use existing documentation.

Comment: BTW, are you aware of the fact, that Thrift does not allow for e.g. two structs including each other? Cyclical or graph-alike structures are possible with some workarounds, but `struct A { 1: B b }` followed by `struct B { 1: A a }` will not work.

Comment: Yes. I'll cross that road when I come to it.